# Improve method to calculate user reputation containing a lot of conditions with rules engine

Tags: c#

I have a method to calculate user reputation based on a lot of nested conditions, the code works but it's not very elegant, the reputation is given based on some rules so I thought using a rule engine would solve the problem but as far as I understand a rule engine would return TRUE if a condition is meet or False otherwise. In my case I need to evaluate two objects User and collections of Entries and know how many times a condition is true to calculate earned points.

Any idea to improve the algorithm?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates and updates the user reputation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">The user</param>
    public void UpdateReputation(User user)
    {
        user.UserReputations.ToList()
            .ForEach(r => this.UnitOfWork.UserReputations.Delete(r));

        foreach (Entry entry in user.Entries)
        {
            user.UserReputations.Add(new UserReputation()
            {
                Points = 25,
                DateCreated = entry.DateCreated,
                ContentInfo = entry,
                User = user,
                Verb = (int)UserReputationVerbType.EntryPublished
            });

            foreach (Vote vote in entry.Votes)
            {
                if (vote.Positive)
                {
                    user.UserReputations.Add(new UserReputation()
                    {
                        Points = 2,
                        DateCreated = vote.DateCreated,
                        ContentInfo = vote.ContentInfo,
                        User = user,
                        Verb = (int)UserReputationVerbType.UserEntryVotedUp
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    user.UserReputations.Add(new UserReputation()
                    {
                        Points = -1,
                        DateCreated = vote.DateCreated,
                        ContentInfo = vote.ContentInfo,
                        User = user,
                        Verb = (int)UserReputationVerbType.UserEntryVotedDown
                    });
                }
            }

            foreach (Favourite favouriteEntry in entry.Favourite)
            {
                user.UserReputations.Add(new UserReputation()
                {
                    Points = 5,
                    DateCreated = favouriteEntry.DateCreated,
                    ContentInfo = favouriteEntry.Entry,
                    User = user,
                    Verb = (int)UserReputationVerbType.UserEntryFavourited
                });
            }
        }

        foreach (Favourite favouriteEntry in user.Favourite)
        {
            user.UserReputations.Add(new UserReputation()
            {
                Points = 2,
                DateCreated = favouriteEntry.DateCreated,
                ContentInfo = favouriteEntry.Entry,
                User = user,
                Verb = (int)UserReputationVerbType.EntryFavourited
            });
        }

   (a lot of conditions ...)
```

Comment: What is it you update at the end? Each condition met with its details or just the sum of `Points`?

Comment: Each condition met adds a new UserReputation row, the points is the sum of them. Some condition are not only True or False, most of them are true multiple times for example how many Entries a user has created awarding 25 points for each of them

Comment: The easiest suggestion that comes to mind is asking the stackoverflow guys how they implemented their own reputation score system. It looks though like you're re-calculating the whole reputation from scratch each time. Why can't you trigger the update for the new condition and just add that to the total reputation.

Comment: @Brian I think is more difficult to implement and less accurate (some reputation depends on other person actions) than re-calculate the reputation from scratch even if it's less efficient

Comment: When are you calculating this? Why do you clear the original set? Can you use db triggers / stored procedures (as a follow up question to the first one I asked)